# How add the parameter Content-disposition in JavaScript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to add the parameter Content-disposition = inline in my code in JavaScript not at my HTML. 
How I can do this ?

```
public downloadImageJpeg(instanceUID: string, format: string): string {
  a.href =  'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/54789364/JPG-logo-highres.jpg';
  a.download = 'image.jpg';
  a.click();
}
```

Comment: if you want to add a parameter to the function simply you can add that. `downloadImageJpeg(instanceUID: string, format: string, Content-disposition? = inline): string {` and by adding ? mark you make it optional in typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add parameter to the function in the typescript file which generate javascript after compile or build add that in the function.

```
public downloadImageJpeg(instanceUID: string, format: string, ContenDisposition? = inline): string {
  a.href =  'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/54789364/JPG-logo-highres.jpg';
  a.download = 'image.jpg';
  a.click();
}
```

By adding `?` after the parameter name it will make is optional and its not mandatory to pass the value of it.

Hope I understood the question and answered it.

Comment: I believe they're talking about the HTTP header `Content-Disposition`, rather than adding an extra parameter to their function. Also, your code isn't valid - JavaScript identifiers can't contain dashes, and `inline` would need to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're sending form data (which you're not), `Content-Disposition` has to be provided by the server as a response header. So in other words, you can't do what you're trying to do.

That said, I think this is an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - it doesn't make sense to use `a.download` if your aim is to just display the image in the browser. Just use an anchor tag, and mark it to open in a new tab using `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I want to display the image in my browser, and to download it too.

I want to add the parameter Content-Disposition because I have a problem with the name of my file. I can't change it ..